# how to add a key using a foxpro index file ( cdx)

Tags: indexing, foxpro, dbf

Is it possible to add a key to index file cdx programmatically using a function like addkey()? I  want to use Ms FoxPro.

An Integrated functions to manipulate a  foxPro index File . I  used that but with clipper 5.2e  Is there  an equivalent in FoxPro

Nb : I use sx_KeyAdd  ( SIX RDD Library  for clipper).

Comment: There are relatively ambitious descriptions in the docs for the "Index" and the "Reindex" commands.
 https://www.vfphelp.com/help/_5wn12pdrt.htm
 https://www.vfphelp.com/help/_5wn12pecy.htm

Comment: In a nutshell, you would traditionally not update single index items explicitly, but rely on the built-in automatic CDX maintenance. And if an index file gets damaged, rebuild it from scratch when the database is idle in the middle of the night. Or if you are having such multi-user/network related troubles frequently, use a more reliable back-end like for example PostgreSql

Answer (score 0):

In FoxPro the database engine isn't a library like it is in Clipper. Therefore there are commands instead of functions to manipulate index files. To add a key to a CDX file you must first open the table exclusively:

```
USE path-and-filename EXCLUSIVE
```

Then you can use the `INDEX` command to add a key. For instance, if you have a column named `fullname` and you want to create a key named `tagName`, you would use the following index command:

```
INDEX ON fullname TAG tagName
```

If you have two columns named `firstname` and `lastname` and you need an index on combined value of both columns, you would use the following index command.

```
INDEX ON lastname+firstname TAG tagName
```

This code assumes you want to sort by last name followed by first name. To manipulate a CDX file from a different language than FoxPro you need a library that is specifically aware of FoxPro index files. While FoxPro's index files are similar to those of dBase and Clipper, they aren't identical.

Index files are automatically maintained by FoxPro when you change an indexed column, that is, the name of the column is listed in the index expression. This happens for all open index files. Index files that are not open are not updated and cannot updated individually. The only way to bring a closed index file up-to-date is to open it and use the `REINDEX`command.

For this reason best practice in FoxPro is to use one CDX file with all index tags per table. While FoxPro supports multiple CDX files and even combinations with IDX files, these are very difficult to work with. The primary CDX file is automatically opened by FoxPro whenever you open the table.

The only option to selectively add records to an index is with the `FOR` clause. You can specify one expression that is evaluated for a record when it's added and when it's updated. These rules should only base on the current record not on external data such as the user that is logged on into the application. When VFP reindexes the table, this expression is evaluated for every record outside of the scope that the record was added in initially.

The `FOR` clause is part of the `INDEX` command. For instance, to create an index on the column `INVOICENO` for all records where the `PAID_ON` column is empty, ie. all unpaid invoices, you would create an index like this:

```
INDEX ON InvoiceNo TAG InvoiceNo FOR NOT EMPTY(Paid_On)
```